# Bootstrap pills multi row weird positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-2

Edit: I realized it was hard to understand the question as it was, so here it goes:
When the pills in my bootstrap nav no longer fits into one row (when decrease width, or adding more pills) the position is not as desired. I would like the 'overflow' to go into a new row, not get stuck in between as for Tesla in the image. To see it in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/burktelefon/ey2bosj2/): decrease the width of the output pane and keep watch on the rightmost pill.

[image]

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li><a href=" #">Audi</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Otherwise we can only guess what might be the problem... (sidenote: you might want to omit the space in front of the hashtag)

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't make a fiddle. I have to hope for someones guess.

Comment: ehrm... using knockout doesn't matter... as you can either include knockout, or strip out the generated html/css using eg. dev tools. Anyway, without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) don't expect to get constructive help

Comment: You are right of course. I finally managed to get a working fiddle.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: The desired behaviour is to have pills that doesn't fit in the first row should "pop down" to the next row, and not be in between rows. (Like Tesla is in the attached image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `&nbsp;` to get the expected result. If you need some space on the right side of the pills you can add the additional CSS:

**The Code (with alternative space, not `&nbsp;` - https://jsfiddle.net/ey2bosj2/2/):**

```
ul.nav-pills li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="control segmentinputgroup form-inline">
  <div class="span12">
    <span></span>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Cooper</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Fiat</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Jaguar</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Kia</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Seat</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tesla</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Volvo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh. Thank you! Knowledge is king :)